# How do I display a list of Person objects in a h:dataTable?

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have a list of `Person` objects with properties like `height`, `sex`, `colour`, etc in a backing bean. How do I display those objects in a `h:dataTable` in JSF?

Comment: In the future, please pay a bit more attention as to how you formulate the question. This question was almost been closed because it was not clear/useful enough. Try to ask the question the smart way, I've cleaned/improved it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load it in bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` and add a getter which returns it.

```
public class Bean {

    private List<Person> persons;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        persons = loadItSomehow();
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can bind it to the `value` of the `<h:dataTable>`. During each step of the iteration, the currently iterated object (in this case, `Person`) is available by the name as definied in the `var` attribute. You can use it to access the properties. You can use `<h:column>` to define table columns.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.persons}" var="person">
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{person.height}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{person.sex}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputText value="#{person.colour}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This will render a HTML `<table>` with one `<tr>` per `Person` with one `<td>` per `<h:column>`.

#### See also:

- [How to use `h:dataTable` in JSF 1.2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html)